# JavaScript heap out of memory Angular Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, out-of-memory

I have an Angular front end application that I am trying to deploy to Heroku. Everything works fine locally but I am getting a  JavaScript heap out of memory error when trying to deploy.

I have found other questions like this that recommend:

```
"start": "node --max_old_space_size=2560 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

but I am not using react.

I have also seen:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js
```

but I am not using node and I'm not sure which file I should put for "yourFile.js"

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "howling-wolfe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod && npm install -g http-server-spa",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 main.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Not sure what else is relevant but can post more code snippets if requested...

Does anyone know an Angular specific solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

edit:

changed my package json to:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod && npm install -g http-server-spa",
"start": "ng serve"
```

Still getting the out of memory error.

here is the full log:

```
2021-04-22T17:44:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-22T17:44:26.258053+00:00 app[web.1]: - Generating browser application bundles...
2021-04-22T17:45:03.226986+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.226995+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2021-04-22T17:45:03.226995+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.226996+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x56a6040]    42577 ms: Scavenge 253.1 (257.7) -> 252.6 (257.9) MB, 2.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.743, current mu = 0.490) allocation failure
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227002+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x56a6040]    43200 ms: Mark-sweep 253.3 (257.9) -> 252.5 (258.4) MB, 600.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.620, current mu = 0.464) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227002+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x56a6040]    43812 ms: Mark-sweep 253.6 (258.4) -> 252.7 (258.9) MB, 505.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.475, current mu = 0.175) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227003+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227019+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227020+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227020+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227042+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory   
2021-04-22T17:45:03.227855+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [ng serve]2021-04-22T17:45:03.228461+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.229077+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.229684+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.230435+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xd34395  [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.231277+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xd64f2e v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.232008+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xd70f66 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.232755+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xd5d14f v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.233484+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xd5d3c8 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel(v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::Runner) [ng serve]  
2021-04-22T17:45:03.234202+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd4fca9 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.241081+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0xd72ec0 void v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks<v8::internal::FullEvacuator, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector>(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*, v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*, v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [ng serve]     
2021-04-22T17:45:03.241798+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xd7375c v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.242495+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xd73925 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.243205+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xd85911 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.243916+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xd41c38 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.244660+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xd43728 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.245380+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.246026+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0xd1524b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.246817+00:00 app[web.1]: 19: 0x105b23f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng serve]2021-04-22T17:45:03.247675+00:00 app[web.1]: 20: 0x1401219  [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:45:03.296152+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
2021-04-22T17:45:03.309877+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-22T17:45:03.310293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 134
2021-04-22T17:45:03.321025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! howling-wolfe@0.0.0 start: 
`ng serve`
2021-04-22T17:45:03.321155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 134
2021-04-22T17:45:03.321325+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-22T17:45:03.321457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the howling-wolfe@0.0.0 start script.
2021-04-22T17:45:03.321559+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-22T17:45:03.335270+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.336923+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run 
can be found in:
2021-04-22T17:45:03.337142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-22T17_45_03_322Z-debug.log
2021-04-22T17:45:03.442652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134   
2021-04-22T17:45:03.518195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-22T17:45:03.525632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-22T17:45:19.028926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-22T17:45:22.453342+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:22.453355+00:00 app[web.1]: > howling-wolfe@0.0.0 start /app    
2021-04-22T17:45:22.453355+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2021-04-22T17:45:22.453355+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:45:31.328834+00:00 app[web.1]: - Generating browser application bundles...
2021-04-22T17:45:42.091209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=howlingwolfefe.herokuapp.com request_id=04ca8010-335b-4d92-a193-ad760452dc47 fwd="24.15.212.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978041+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978047+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978047+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978056+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x49e1040]    47122 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 252.2 (257.4) -> 251.2 (258.7) MB, 510.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.522, current mu = 0.121) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978056+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x49e1040]    47735 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 252.3 (257.7) -> 251.5 (258.9) MB, 573.2 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.341, current mu = 0.066) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978057+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978100+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978101+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978102+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-22T17:46:10.978126+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory   
2021-04-22T17:46:10.979222+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [ng serve]2021-04-22T17:46:10.980548+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.982020+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.984155+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.984784+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xd34395  [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.990332+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xd64f2e v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.991142+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xd70f66 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.992271+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xd5d14f v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.992893+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xd5d3c8 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel(v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::Runner) [ng serve]  
2021-04-22T17:46:10.993517+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd4fca9 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.994202+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0xd72ec0 void v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks<v8::internal::FullEvacuator, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector>(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*, v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*, v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [ng serve]     
2021-04-22T17:46:10.994879+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xd7375c v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:10.995575+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xd73925 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.000235+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xd85911 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.000867+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xd41c38 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.001485+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xd43728 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.002095+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.002692+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0xd1524b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.003391+00:00 app[web.1]: 19: 0x105b23f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng serve]2021-04-22T17:46:11.004242+00:00 app[web.1]: 20: 0x1401219  [ng serve]
2021-04-22T17:46:11.092210+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
2021-04-22T17:46:11.112815+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-22T17:46:11.113171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 134
2021-04-22T17:46:11.125677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! howling-wolfe@0.0.0 start: 
`ng serve`
2021-04-22T17:46:11.125787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 134
2021-04-22T17:46:11.125923+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-22T17:46:11.126013+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the howling-wolfe@0.0.0 start script.
2021-04-22T17:46:11.126092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-22T17:46:11.129772+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-22T17:46:11.136280+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run 
can be found in:
2021-04-22T17:46:11.136361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-22T17_46_11_126Z-debug.log
2021-04-22T17:46:11.205229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134   
2021-04-22T17:46:11.262211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-22T17:46:12.831264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=howlingwolfefe.herokuapp.com request_id=682bcfc3-dee9-467c-91f9-465367c289ea fwd="24.15.212.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-22T17:46:12.960639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=howlingwolfefe.herokuapp.com request_id=5607ba7b-3ed2-428a-afb5-36770d6a8d2e fwd="24.15.212.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-22T17:46:14.048038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=howlingwolfefe.herokuapp.com request_id=ae400031-c340-4c29-884a-270c61fa2ebd fwd="24.15.212.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: how do you deploy to heroku? How do you run on heroku?

Comment: angular apps are usually built before deployment.

Comment: @kvetis I am pushing to github and clicking the manual deploy button on my linked heroku app

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @kvetis posted my package.json. Is there anything else you want to see?

Comment: How do you run your appliaction on heroku?

Comment: do you run build before and then copy your files over?

Comment: @kvetis I don't know, maybe that is what I'm looking for here. I've deployed many apps to heroku but never an Angular app and I can't figure out why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Change your build command to :-

```
"heroku-postbuild": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod && npm install -g http-server-spa"
```

and change 8000 to the value you want to change it to.

Comment: That might have worked but now I am getting: "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"  Do you know what that means?

Comment: you have to increase heroku timeout.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Updated question with full log. I am still getting the same error with 8 gb of memory

Comment: nope this is a different one. as i believe your build is successful now. which was failing earlier right?

Comment: It is still failing

Comment: build or ng serve? there is a difference

Comment: "2021-04-22T17:45:03.227042+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory "

Comment: it doesn't answer what i asked.

Comment: looks like it is the ng serve that is failing. I don't know though

Comment: locally I use ng serve

Comment: i am asking about heroku.

Comment: I don't know how to start a server on heroku... I just click deploy and open the app and get the above log

Comment: when you click on deploy there must me some command running, until you tell that can't do anything. plus this question was around build error which is resolved. you should raise another question regarding what you are asking.\

Comment: There is no command that I type in. I just click Deploy Branch.  also the issue is not resolved because in the log above, I'm still getting: "2021-04-22T17:45:03.227042+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"